# How to create site custom field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, client-object-model

How can i create custom fields for a site or sub site 
like Title and Description 
i've sub sites and every site has unique banner and some information
i want the user will be able to add these information in some kind of setting form
as well as he change the site title and description
on other hand i can retrieve them also with javascript to append them to the design.
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of property bag of web object. It stores properties as key value pairs. Check this for reference: http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2011/10/03/making-use-of-the-property-bag-in-the-ecmascript-client-object-model/

Comment: Its very useful sure i'll make use of it 
i'll search to make it work with file field to make banner upload field